# python: what is a best way to find paths with x length in 2d array?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

Assume that I have an array like this `[[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 5], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0]]`

each index is a node index so `[0, 1, 0, 0]` means node0 has a edge to node1 with length 1

`[1, 0, 2, 5]` means node1 has edges to node0, node2 and node3 with following lengths 1, 2 and 5

(Every edge is bidirected <->)

And with this 2d array, I want to find out a number of paths with exact x length for all nodes.

but a visited edge will not be used again.

if x is 3, node 0-1-2 so should return 2 (node0 to node1 = 1, node1 to node 2 = 2, sum of length is 3 and used 2 paths)

(if the length of between node1 and node3 is 2, it won't be included as already used node0-node1 path so still must return 2)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, as you seem to be using the word 'path' to refer to both edges and actual paths. I interpret the question as 'Find the maximum number of edge-disjoint simple paths, such that each path's edges have weight summing to x'. However, the fact that 0-1-2 is two paths seems to contradict this interpretation

Comment: Oh okay, I called edges as paths because I refer nodes to some sort of subway stations, my bad about forgetting about graph terms, every path in my question should be edge.

each node is like a station and your interpretation is right. visited "edge" will not be used again. `node0 <- 1 -> node1 <- 2 -> node2` (so the sum of lengths of edges is 3)

Comment: Can you edit the question with the corrected terms?